# In my project's url, typing a non-existent word leads to a custom 404 error page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my project's url, typing a non-existent word leads to a custom 404 error page. But if you put a period at the end of the word, it leads to such a page instead of the custom 404 page. How can I make the custom 404 page work in every case.

Custom error -
[image]

Error with dot in url :

[image]

Comment: The 404 in the first image is returned by your application, the error in the second image is returned by the web server. In your case IIS. 
Do you configure 404 pages for IIS in your web.config?

Comment: @L01NL There is only this part, is it enough?

<system.web>
    <!--<customErrors mode="On">
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/_404" />
       <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error/_500" />
    </customErrors>-->
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to understand how a custom 404 page can be defined via IIS. For this purpose, refer this page: https://www.bruceclay.com/blog/microsoft-iis-custom-404-error-page-configuration/

## IIS 8.5

[image]

[image]

## IIS 10

[image]

Now, let's understand your situation. You have some rule in IIS which says that if you have your  ending with some pattern (like an alphabumeric string), then a certain page is triggered. That page is loading a custom 404 template to display this error. Since your path pattern did not match this IIS rule, you get the error we discussed.

If you want to solve the problem with very simple steps, then follow the guidance I have shared at the start of this answer and specify your custom 404 to be loaded when a page is not found.

If you want to clean up your older configuration as well, so your new 404 strategy will be applied always, then you can look into [IIS URL rewriting and routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing) and find your old rule and fix or delete it, depending on what suits you best.